# Propertychanged delegate in BindableProperty is called twice with datatrigger

Tags: xamarin.forms, datatrigger, propertychanged, bindable

I know that this question was already asked but I was not able to find a solution for my problem.

My question is this: I've a bindable property in a custom control that is exposed to show a text (the pagetitle), and I need that this text is cutted when the view is in portrait.
I want that this bindable property takes its value from a property inherited from a base (PageTitle) and than that a converter do the work to cut the word when it's needed.
I have created a datatrigger to fire that converter, but I think that I misunderstanded how it works, because on the first rotation all works as expected, but from the second rotation the Propertychanged delegate is fired twice and I didn't understand why.

I was able to solve this specific problem using a Label binded to the property that I use as parameter in my converter, but it's not a clean way to achieve the result and I would understand if something is wrong with my datatrigger and what.

I've a created a simple demo project [published on git here](https://github.com/fgiacomelli/InheritBindable) that explains better what I mean, in the first row I've inserted the control with the bindable property that doesn't work, and in the thirth the solution that works but that it's surely not the best practice to do it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I know that the whole source code is being linked, but I don't believe that it's an encouraging way to anyone help. You've already contextualized us. A [mcve] as part of the question would be appreciated.

Comment: ok, thanks for your suggestion, I thinked that with a simple, full and working demo project all should be easier.
But I can't add the code here because I need more space to paste what I need. So what do you suggest?